# Agenda job library, How to execute cron every last day of the month at mid night or last minute of the day

Tags: javascript, cron, agenda

Agenda job library, please help me to run cron on every last day of the month at 23:50.

```
const cron = job.create('sendInvoice', {
      msg: 'Hello world',
});
await cron.repeatEvery('0 0 * * * *').repeatEvery('1 month').save(); //Executive daily
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need a cron expression for your case (you can use an online generator eg. [this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)). I would also define the job, and then schedule it with `every` instead of manually working with it (although it's possible too).

The following code should work the way you want it:

```
const Agenda = require('agenda');

const agenda = new Agenda({ db: { address: /* your mongodb connection string */ } });

agenda.define('yourJobName', (job) => {
  // do something
}

agenda.on('ready', () => {
  const schedule = '0 50 23 L * ? *'; // every last day of the month at 23:50
  agenda.every(schedule, 'yourJobName');
}

agenda.start();
```

Comment: Thank you @kuba. I already implemented in other way...but I will test this..Appreciate for you answer..

Comment: @NaisargParmar let me know how it goes, and please accept my answer if it's adequate.